# SSRS 2005 - Border issue exporting to Microsoft Excel 2003

Tags: excel, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, excel-2003

I'm working on a SSRS report which is to be exported in PDF as well as Excel 2003 formats.

In the report, I have a rectangle having several tables & text boxes with border style of all but rectangle marked as "None".

When I preview the report & export as PDF, the borders appear only around the rectangle & all the other elements within are borderless, but when I export it as Excel format, borders are mysteriously appearing around various text boxes out of nowhere.

Why is this happening at all?

Snapshot of PDF:

[image: Snapshot of PDF]

Snapshot of Excel:

[image: Snapshot of Excel]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed a workaround for the same.

I got rid of `rectangle` control & brought all the controls outside `rectangle`.
Then I manipulated the borders again on all the elements & it worked as desired.

Please share, if you find a better potential solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid I don't know the answer to that particular question, but SSRS are known for having problems with Excel (and Word) rendering. In our case we decided to go with [OfficeWriter](http://www.officewriter.com/officewriter-for-sql-server-reporting-services.aspx)